# How to get data from multiple databases in one query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm using a Java driver for SQLite 3 and wanted to find out if there was any means to get data from multiple databases (db1.db, db2.db) in one query?

Does any driver for SQLite3 support this at the moment?

Say db1 has 100 rows and db2 has 100 rows, my requirement is to get 200 rows by querying these by a single query.

Comment: why you use more than one database? one is not enough?

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably want to look at the `ATTACH DATABASE` command:

http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html

> The ATTACH DATABASE statement adds another database file to the current database connection.

Here's a tutorial on how to use it:

http://longweekendmobile.com/2010/05/29/how-to-attach-multiple-sqlite-databases-together/